# Unable to extend LightSwitch HTML Client visual collection(`contentItem.value.data`) using jquery extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am extending the `contentItem.value.data` with the Jquery `extend` but the changes are not reflected in the target object. And after sometimes it get reflected. I think something has delayed the setting the value to the particular property.

```
var based = contentItem.value.data[0]; //data will contain several properties and `EmployeeID-9` is one of them

$.extend(based,{EmployeeID:4});
```

And now after extending the EmployeeID still has `9` but after sometimes(some delay) it has `4`.

How can i extend the contentItem data is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Michael Washington Could you please tell why this happening?

Comment: Please can you provide a little more background as to why you're using the extend.  Also a little more info regarding your sample could help e.g. what are the data tables involved, what does the visual collection contain etc. etc.  With a little more info I'll try and help.